# How to I get GCC compiler to work?

Tags: compiling, gcc

So I am new to programming C. I am using Vim as my editor and GCC as my compiler, but its not working quite right. Lets say I am making a basic program to determine if a number is odd or even. Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    int i;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &i);

    printf("%d\n", i);
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
        printf("Your number is even.\n");
    }
    else if(i % 2 != 0)
    {
        printf("Your number is odd.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if I am programming this wrong, or GCC is just not a good compiler, or whatever. I am running Linux, which I dual boot with Windows. 
Now I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to stop the process, and only then does it print me back my number, and tell if it is odd or even. It isn't just this one, a lot of other programs with similar formats seem to do this to.

```
~ $ ./test
Enter a number: 45
45                         //I press enter, nothing happends. Ctrl-d 
Your number is even.       //ctrl-d again
~ $
```

Comment: Great question! But... probably a better question on [stack overflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure if I am programming this wrong, or gcc is just not a good compiler, or whatever.

The first one: `scanf("%d\n", &i);` should be `scanf("%d", &i);`.

Also other errors:

- The second argument of `main()` should be casted either to a pointer to an array of characters or to a pointer to a pointer to a character: `char *argv[]` or `char **argv`;
- If `i` is not a number, it will still be casted to an integer both in `if(i % 2 == 0)` and `else if(i % 2 != 0)` in order for the expression to be evaluated (in fact you'll never get to the `else` block using that code, as either `if(i % 2 == 0)` or `else if(i % 2 != 0)`, being `i` implicitly casted to an integer, will evaluate to true). Have a read at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753346/determine-if-a-c-string-is-a-valid-int-in-c) for more proper ways to check if a string is numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, what the heck. I'll take a stab at answering it anyhow.

Short answer: remove the `\n` from the argument to scanf. When I do this, your code behaves as expected (well, to be persnickety, I also had to change `argv[]` into `*argv[]`.)

Longer answer: you shouldn't really ever use scanf; it usually gets you into trouble.

Hmm... my longer answer was shorter than my short answer. Ah well.

Comment: Thanks! That worked very well. What do you recommend using instead of scanf, that would allow me to set variable to user input?

Comment: I hate to be snide, but the short answer is: Don't write this kind of code using C.  Here's a longer answer: Read a full line of text and parse it by hand.